# Camera (F12) wont render correctly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera, transparency, glass

I have a small problem. The f12 wont render correctly. This is my viewport:

[image: Viewport image]

and this is the f12 image:

[image]

Blender File here: https://jmp.sh/pIbvOCR

Could someone please help me :)?

Comment: Check in the outliner, you have plane object that is excluded from render.

Comment: did you checked if  your camera is too close?m you can move it with Key 0 
for first person pov, then control+f then move with w a s d and q and e, did you had set some light?, sun? etc?

Comment: @AlanParson Nope Camera is alright. Check the screenshot of the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the little Icon with the Camera in Outliner its not checked. 
Click that Camera to get the plane appear in Render view

[image]

By Clicking The Camera Icon in outliner you are restricting the plane to appear in Render.